# How can I pass a variable as an option when creating a jQuery UI accordion?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code:

```
$(acc_id).accordion({
    alwaysOpen: false,
    active: false,
    autoheight: false,
    header: 'h3.ui-accordion3-header',
    clearStyle: true
});
```

I want to send a variable to it, since the header should be unique.

Answer (score 2):

```
var header = 'h3.ui-accordion3-header';
$(acc_id).accordion({
        alwaysOpen: false,
        active: false,
        autoheight: false,
        header: header,
        clearStyle: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach given in the examples by ChaosPandion and rochal (where the header is defined from a variable) seems best to me, but another useful thing to know about is that you can redefine any option on an accordion by using the "option" option, like this:

```
$(acc_id).accordion({
                                alwaysOpen: false,
                                active: false,
                                autoheight: false,
                                header: 'placeholder',
                                clearStyle: true
                        });
$(acc_id).accordion('option', 'header', 'h3.ui-accordion3-header');
```

In this way you can create the accordion and then, afterwards, set the header value.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function Accord(acc_id, header_id) {
    $('#' + acc_id).accordion({
        alwaysOpen: false,
        active: false,
        autoheight: false,
        header: header_id,
        clearStyle: true
    });
}
```

Comment: The parameter name header_id is confusing because it can be any valid selector.

Comment: yes, good point. I like to mark stuff with _id when I need to pass string selector to distinguish between passing the entire object: header = $('.header') vs header_id = 'header'. I probably need better suffix/prefix for it.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you're looking for, but something like this may work

```
$(acc_id).accordion({
    alwaysOpen: false,
    active: false,
    autoheight: false,
    header: $(this).find('h3.ui-accordion3-header').text(),
    clearStyle: true
});
```

Comment: This will probably raise an error internally. If you remove the .text() it should work. In either case this doesn't answer the question.